# Puppeteer production to Vercel performance issues Next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, puppeteer, server-side-rendering

I am trying to push my site to prod however either the memory is too big or the performance is too slow and returns a 504 status. According to vercel this is because the request took too long? I am new to puppeteer and have tried everything but I do not understand why it works locally but not in prod.

```
const chrome = require("chrome-aws-lambda");

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    const browser = await chrome.puppeteer.launch(
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
        ? {
            args: chrome.args,
            executablePath: await chrome.executablePath,
            headless: true,
          }
        : {}
    );

    const aboutBlankPage = (await browser.pages())[0];
    if (aboutBlankPage) {
      await aboutBlankPage.close();
    }

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://mars.nasa.gov/msl/weather/");

    const nasaWeatherDataScrape = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const high = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".celsius .high")).map(
        (x) => x.innerText
      );
      const low = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".celsius .low")).map(
        (x) => x.innerText
      );
      return {
        high,
        low,
      };
    });

    console.log(nasaWeatherDataScrape, "in");
    res.json(nasaWeatherDataScrape);

    const newPage = (await browser.pages())[0];

    await newPage.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    res.status(400).json({
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Did you come to a solution for this problem? Vercel is too slow. Wondering if I should migrate to AWS eC2 or upgrade from Vercel hobby plan, or any other performance enhancements?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the default Chromium package exceeds [the 50MB function size limit on Vercel](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview#serverless-function-size).

You will have to add `chrome-aws-lambda` deliberately at a version where it is below that limit on Vercel servers. I suspect your issue specifically is the `chrome-aws-lambda` version.

Please try

```
npm i --save chrome-aws-lambda@^8.0.2 puppeteer-core@^8.0.0
```

Here is a nice tutorial explaining the process. https://gist.github.com/kettanaito/56861aff96e6debc575d522dd03e5725

And a simplified working example.
https://gist.github.com/agungjk/ff542367470d156478f7381af2cf7e60